# PHP: need server time and date to run sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to send email to multiple persons at specific time and date. Specific time and date are

```
1. At 10am each morning
2. On Sunday morning at 10:01 am
3. On the last day of each month,at 10:02 am
4. On April 1 10:03 am
5. On July 1 10:03 am
6. On October 1 10:03 am
7. On Jan 1 10:03 am
8. on Jan 1 10:04 am
```

email will send from server and recipient will be collected from Database. `Please help me to get these time and date automatically with PHP. This process will automatic`.

Comment: Do you know anything about cron?

Comment: create cron job..in phpmyadmin

Comment: @sectus I don't know about cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create a cronjob that will run a PHP script that processes it.

You can learn how to setup a cronjob either here (if running your own server) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron, or contact your hosting provider for assistance.

As for getting the time and date in PHP, you can use the date function (https://www.php.net/function.date).

---

**Example**

Cron

1. `0 10 * * * user /path/to/file1.php`
2. `03 10 1 1 * user /path/to/file7.php`

Code

1. `if(date("H") == 10)`
2. `if(date("M") == 1 && date("d") == 1 && date("H") == 10 && date("i") == 3)`